# MySQL - where condition with small int

Tags: mysql, string, int

I have tasks table with status of type  smallint(5). It has 0 or 1 or 2 values.

When i run this query, it give me result

```
 SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE  `status` = 'EMPTY'
```

There is no EMPTY value in status, then how i can get result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impicit data conversion is happening for example

```
select cast('empty' as int); 

+----------------------+
| cast('empty' as int) |
+----------------------+
|                    0 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I'm afraid it's up to you to make sure you compare like with like.

Comment: You mean string 'EMPTY' was converted to 0?

Answer (score 0):

If the values can only be `0`, `1` or `2` then this should give all rows with a `0` status:

```
SELECT *
FROM tasks
WHERE status = 0
```

If there are `NULL` values then you can get those by changing the `WHERE` to

```
WHERE status IS NULL
```

`NULL` is not the same as `0`, so to get both, you would need to do:

```
WHERE status IS NULL OR status = 0
```

Comment: Why it give me result for `status` = 'EMPTY'   where EMPTY is string and it is not equal to  0 or 1 or 2

Comment: I'm not sure how you can have a status of EMPTY if the column is a small int?